# How to make a date range search function

Tags: php, search, date-range

This is my script that show the search box for searching the data from csv file with the keyword

```
<?php
$file  = fopen('aws.csv', 'r');
$output ='';
if (isset($_POST['searchVal'])) {
$words = $_POST['searchVal'];

$words = array(preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#"," ",$words));

$words = array_map('preg_quote', $words);
// The argument becomes '/wii|guitar/i', which means 'wii or guitar, case-insensitive'
$regex = '/'.implode('|', $words).'/i';

while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {  
    list($name, $age, $hobbies) = $line;

    if(preg_match($regex, $age)) {
        $output .=  "$name, $age, $hobbies<br/>";
    }

    }
}       
?>

<form action="search1.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search">
</form>

<?php echo $output; ?>
```

Now I want to make a range search function for example I want search the date between 20150727-20150730... 20150727 means 27-July-2015

Comment: convert\import cs in to db would make this so much easier - is it an option

Comment: @Dagon cant ...because my project is using csv ... :(

Comment: the only fields you are showing is name, age and hobbies. where are the date values that you want to search on?

Comment: not a very practical storage method... would not take long to convert to database...even a free cloud service

Comment: @frymaster because that is my example code...lets say the $age I change to $date...

Comment: http://csv.thephpleague.com/query-filtering/  You could check out some of the querying and filtering options in that library.